# Frustrating ImportRange not showing immediately and therefore affecting Script to complete task

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

Can you help me with this frustrating issue that I started to have, and I'm guessing that the `ImportRange` might be the problem:

**Summary of my issue**:

I've created a template spreadsheet, and authorized 3 `ImportRange` (actually only once since they all pull data from the same Master sheet), everything would work fine, but after a couple of days, the `ImportRange` would not show immediately when the document is open (appears disappears then appears again = within 5 to 10 secs) and a script using the data of one of the `ImportRange` would fail to complete the task as a consequence (This is my main problem). This started to happen when I've tried few new things with my spreadsheet: I've added that third `ImportRange` to pull data (from the same Master sheet). Without **creating at the beginning** this 3rd `ImportRange` the spreadsheet has no issue and the script would complete the task. Once the issue starts, if I remove this 3rd `Importrange`, the problem will still remain.

While writing this question: I've  tried to pull the data of this 3rd `ImportRange` from a different source, but it stays on 'Loading ...' forever and would not show up the Allow Access blue button to authorize it.

Instead of writing a long post, if you want to have a closer look at the details of my issue, please read it within this shared sheet: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DlxEbh2jWNuc1x4UYCXLSPE_4sj_AMflWbeF6ffDps8/edit?usp=sharing)

Can anyone bring some light on this issue and help me find a solution?

Comment: Are you working with multiple spreadsheets or is everything in the same spreadsheet?  If a single spreadsheet you might try using named ranges instead of import range.

Comment: For each subject and grade level, I create a spreadsheet and each spreadsheet has the 3 importrange fromula pulling Data from a (different) Master Spreadsheet. This Master spreadsheet contains 3 tabs: First tabs (data about student,Second tab: possibility to control weeks, Third tab: emails and classes of all teachers of all subjects and grades).

Comment: The guidelines of this sites require that all the relevant details should be included on question. One of the reasons is that the external files could be deleted making the information about the question incomplete for future readers.

Comment: Regarding the problem, it looks to be a reliability issue of Google Sheets rather than a programming issue, so I think that this question if off-topic for this site. It's worthy to mention that there have being reports of IMPORTRANGE temporary failures across several sites including this and the official Google Docs Editors Help Forum.

Comment: Thank you Rubén, and sorry If I missed the guidelines. I did specify the tags related to the topic of my question, which this site do consider, and perhaps an expert could help investigate this issue further and benefit any other reader coming across the same issue. I've also tried to post a question in the Google Docs Forum. Thank you for your help